# Why am I getting a ruby error on Guard:watch in command line?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, laravel, laravel-4

I am creating an application/site in laravel 4. I am setting up Laravel with laravel-guard which helps build assets really easily and creates modular set ups so you can minify css and js quickly.

I am running through everything as expected [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Guard)

I have got the correct ruby version etc running so thats cool.

When I run the command `php artisan guard:make` it works perfectly fine but when I try and run

```
php artisan guard:watch
```

I get some really weird errors on there and they do not work well at all.

The errors I am getting are:

```
17:21:54 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/phpunit' or find class Guard::Phpunit
17:21:54 - ERROR - /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `activate'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:100:in `plugin_class'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:166:in `guard'
> [#] /Freelance/Current Projects/knight-dragon/knightdragon/Guardfile:12:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:121:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/setuper.rb:144:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/setuper.rb:62:in `setup'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:24:in `start'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:96:in `start'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `start'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/guard-2.2.1/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/guard:19:in `load'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/guard:19:in `<main>'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
> [#] /Users/mdunbavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
17:21:54 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#] undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass
```

This is what is in my gem list:

```
guard (2.2.1, 1.4.0)
guard-coffeescript (1.3.4)
guard-concat (0.0.3)
guard-livereload (2.0.0)
guard-phpunit (0.1.4)
guard-sass (1.3.2)
```

I have looked at my gems list and it seems to be there so I cannot figure it out at all.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: To answer your question specifically about getting a Ruby error: These console commands are wrappers around the "Guard" toolset, which is a Ruby tool (a package available via Ruby's package manager "gem"). By using this, you are implicitly using some Ruby as well. (But you probably knew that much, hence the comment rather than an answer). How to fix the error I'll leave to more knowledgable people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem related yo Guard::PHPUnit, I also could not make it work. If you don't need PHPUnit, a workaround: edit your Guardfile and comment this block:

```
#guard :phpunit, :all_on_start => false, :tests_path => 'app/tests/', :cli => '--colors -c phpunit.xml', :require => false do
#  # Run any test in app/tests upon save.
#  watch(%r{^.+Test\.php$})
#
#  # When a view file is updated, run tests.
#  # Tip: you probably only want to run your integration tests.
#  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.php}) { Dir.glob('app/tests/**/*.php') }
#
#  # When a file is edited, try to run its associated test.
#  # Save app/models/User.php, and it will run app/tests/models/UserTest.php
#  watch(%r{^app/(.+)/(.+)\.php$}) { |m| "app/tests/#{m[1]}/#{m[2]}Test.php"}
#end
```

Now it should work, but PHPUnit will be disabled:

```
php artisan guard:watch
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo gem install  guard-phpunit2

And edit:phpunit -> phpunit2

```
guard :phpunit2, :all_on_start => false, :tests_path => 'app/tests/', :cli => '--colors -c phpunit.xml' do
  # Run any test in app/tests upon save.
  watch(%r{^.+Test\.php$})

  # When a view file is updated, run tests.
  # Tip: you probably only want to run your integration tests.
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.php}) { Dir.glob('app/tests/**/*.php') }

  # When a file is edited, try to run its associated test.
  # Save app/models/User.php, and it will run app/tests/models/UserTest.php
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)/(.+)\.php$}) { |m| "app/tests/#{m[1]}/#{m[2]}Test.php"}
end
```